# JSX return a html segment

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple loop to display something returned from a remote API:

```
<p>
{
   Object.keys(today).map(function (key) {
     var item=today[key];
     return (
       <a href={"/books/"+item.bookid+".html"} key={item.bookid}>{item.title}</a>
     );
   })
}
</p>
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now I want to add more output:

`<a href={"/books/"+item.bookid+".html"} key={item.bookid}>{item.title}</a>({item.fromnow} years ago)`

When I do the above, I get an error : `Unexpected token`.

If I move the `years ago` text to be inside the `<a>...</a>`, it is fine:

```
<a href={"/books/"+item.bookid+".html"} key={item.bookid}>{item.title}({item.fromnow} years ago)</a>
```

I am not sure if I have made myself clear.

Of course, I can accept that the `xxx years ago` becomes a part of the link, but I need to know how to separate that part from the link.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you remember to wrap it all inside a single, outermost enclosing tag? For example: `<div><a href={"/books/"+item.bookid+".html"} key={item.bookid}>{item.title}</a>（{item.fromnow} years ago）</div>`

Comment: Thanks! I found out this is exactly the issue. Now I put them in one `span` and it works fine.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Just remember that no matter whether it's inside the `render()` method specifically or some other class method, all JSX code must be wrapped in exactly one outermost HTML tag (_i.e._, it has no sibling elements). https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score 1):

This is because as of React 15, you still have to wrap adjacent elements in an enclosing tag. You might have received this error:

```
Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag
```

When you add in the years ago to the return value, it's actually returning two elements, the `<a>` and the `years ago` text.

```
<a href={"/books/"+item.bookid+".html"} key={item.bookid}>{item.title </a>
({item.fromnow} years ago)
```

Wrapping them in a `<div>` or `<span>` is the common solution to this problem.

```
return (
  <span>
    <a href={"/books/"+item.bookid+".html"} key={item.bookid}>{item.title}</a>
    ({item.fromnow} years ago)
  </span>
);
```